# How can i connect user with a connection by using Guacamole REST API

Tags: guacamole

I want to connect user with a connection, but Guacamole does not currently have an API documentation.

Is there a way to do that with Guacamole REST API?

Comment: Here you will find an unofficial documation based on Guacamole version 1.1.0: https://github.com/ridvanaltun/guacamole-rest-api-documentation

Comment: yeah, it's already my repo 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,

Firstly i created a token

**Endpoint:**

```
POST {{baseURL}}/api/tokens
```

**x-www-form-urlencoded:**

```
username: guacadmin
password: guacadmin
```

**Sample Response:**

```
{
    "authToken": "8144B9B1EBAF73E8EDCE08EF5C145F49C1C9F563F13E21BF7A1CEC43E74011A4",
    "username": "guacadmin",
    "dataSource": "postgresql",
    "availableDataSources": [
        "postgresql",
        "postgresql-shared"
    ]
}
```

Then i send a PATCH request using `json-patch`:

**Endpoint:**

```
PATCH {{baseURL}}/api/session/data/{{dataSource}}/users/{{username}}/permissions?token={{authToken}}
```

**Sample Request Body:**

```
[
   {
    "op":"add",
    "path": "/connectionPermissions/2",
    "value": "READ"
   }
 ]
```

That's it.